# iOS app show error alert during installation and break install

Tags: ios, xamarin, configuration, provisioning-profile

I build AdHock version application, but it not insalling to device.

[image]

I check ProvisionProfile it works good.

Entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
        <array>
            <string>iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
        </array>
        <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
        <array>
            <string>CloudDocuments</string>
        </array>
        <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
        <array>
            <string>iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
        </array>
        <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
        <array>
            <string>Production</string>
        </array>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>G9XDHMDJ7M.com.binw.Eco</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en,ru</string>
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>ru</string>
    </array>

    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>7.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Economatica.iOS</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.5.</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1429</string>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Economatica</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array/>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
     <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>
    <key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.binw.eco</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I can see in log this records:

```
Jan 31 17:02:59 iPhone-5s-Dev installd(libmis.dylib)[45] <Notice>: entitlement '<private>' has value not permitted by provisioning profile '<private>'

Jan 31 17:02:59 iPhone-5s-Dev installcoordinationd[100] <Notice>: -[IXSClientConnection _client_promiseWithUUID:didCancelWithReason:client:]: Client <private> was not interested in UUID <private>
```

You can see full log: https://gist.github.com/maukur/6ca08e64c726dfc1c357f61e4f35b5cc

Also i try remove `keychain-access-groups` block, 
or replace   `<string>G9XDHMDJ7M.com.binw.Eco</string>` to   `<string>com.binw.Eco</string>` it not solve the problem,

Comment: Doesn't seem like they keychain-access-group identifier matches the bundle identifier.

Comment: @Cheesebaron i look at profile and profile looks good. [profile screen](https://ibb.co/hMFFDm)

Comment: check the Device's UDID . is that Register at developer account?.

Comment: @MAhipalSingh, I checked UDID and it was registered into my devoloper acount.

Comment: and while downloading provision profile from developer account, did you select all the devices option ?

Comment: @MAhipalSingh yes. I sign it proifile new app with old bundle id (com.binw.Eco) and it work.

Comment: but your info plist is showing: "com.binw.eco" and in entitlement its "com.binw.Eco". Pls make sure its should be same

Comment: @MAhipalSingh i found error in my code. I don`t register iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't register `iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)`.

I remove all records from `Entitlements` and app deployed to device.

Also i can register `iCloud.$(CFBundleIdentifier)` and it must work too.